# How to print Activiti workflow task's values into Alfresco Share

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, activiti

I have a workflow to manage employee petitions, that starts with some fields at starter form. The next task, allows a responsable user to approve or reject the initiator user's petition.

I want to show the values of starting form into the approve/reject form, so I created a custom `.ftl` file for every field that I want print the label and *the value*. Now I have hard-coded the values to the this:

[image]

My problem here, is how to get the value from the first form and print it at the second form (values that I need are where says "200€" and my name).

I'm using Alfresco Community 5.1 and his own Activiti.

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide proper version of Alfresco and Activiti you are using.

Comment: Updated. Alfresco Community 5.1 and current Activiti (integrated)

Answer (score 3):

**Solution 1** : keep IDs of the fields identical in both the forms. this will make the field *editable* in the second form.

**Solution 2** : create a *process variable*, set its value after the first form has been submitted. then, in the second form display the value of the *process variable*.

Comment: The first solution was my first idea too. And it doen't works, because I need a label text, not an editable field (it is information about task). You're second solution seems fine, that is I'm trying to do, but I don't know how to read a process variable from Alfresco Share.

Comment: https://forums.alfresco.com/forum/developer-discussions/workflow/dynamic-assignment-using-process-variable-01282008-1406 - this should help you.